# Intercept Hibernate Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, encryption, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate SessionFactory to  retrieve information from database.  Problem is that the "encrypted_field" database field below is now encrypted and breaks the SQL query.

This is the old SQL query I'm trying to convert into Hibernate:

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary order by codetype DESC,code, LEN(encrypted_field) DESC
```

Is there a way to fix this in Hibernate?  I'm thinking of some Hibernate Interceptor that will allow me to decrypt the "encrypted_field" just before Hibernate applies the "order by" criterias to the ResultSet.  Is this possible?

Comment: How were you decrypting before the conversion to Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, [interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) could resolve your issue (onLoad - for decryption info and onSave for encryption)?

Comment: Yup worked for me.  First time I heard about Hibernate interceptors, interesting...

Answer (score 1):

One idea: you create a transient field to the field decrypted. For example:

```
@ Transient
private String getDescryptedField () {
    return descrypt (encriptedField);
}
```